# Using Datagrid within RowDetailsTemplate of another Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, toolkit

I would like to use a DataGrid within the RowDetailsTempalte of another Datagrid.  This inner Datagrid should have its columns bound to a property of the current object in the outer Datagrid.  For example, if the outer Datagrid is displaying all contacts by first name and last name, if I select a row I should be able to see another Datagrid containing all phone numbers associated with that contact. What I am most interested in is how the data of the inner Datagrid binds to the data of the outer Datagrid.  Here is some XAML that I have so far to start with:

```
<data:DataGrid MinHeight="700" x:Name="contacts">
                <data:DataGrid.Columns>                       
                    <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></data:DataGridTextColumn>                        
                 </data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="Black">
                            <StackPanel Background="White" Margin="16">
                                <data:DataGrid DataContext="Contact.Phones">

                                </data:DataGrid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </data:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last answer on this thread helped me: [How is access inner Datagrid in Silverlight?](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/16838.aspx).

On the inner DataGrid I set `ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}"` and removed the `DataContext`.

Answer (score -3):

Use the RowDetailsTemplate instead: [DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28VS.95%29.aspx).

You can bind to the `DetailsVisibilityChanged` event, and that will pass you the `DataContext` of the row that was clicked. From there you can retrieve the details data and update the `RowDetailsTemplate` accordingly.

Comment: I cant find any reference to that event. Is there a better link that refers that property in detail?  Also I am already using the RowDetailsTemplate.